# Which branch should workflow files be located on for GitHub Actions to execute them?

Tags: github-actions

I have created on my main branch with

```
on:  
  push:
      branches: [ test ]
```

I have noticed, that while I can trigger it manually, and it will work, it will not actually trigger if I push to `test`. For that, I needed to create that same action file on `test`. Now, it seems like I don't even need to have the action on the `main` branch, is that correct?

So why does even the option so specify the branch that it should trigger on exist? It only triggers on the branches the file exists anyway. That said, I found it frustrating that I have to merge my one file from main to my test branch, is there a way to trigger the action automatically on push even if I do not have it on my `test` branch, only on `main`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The order of operations in a workflow run triggered by push or pull request is described in the [reference documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#about-workflow-triggers):

> 1. An event occurs on your repository. The event has an associated commit SHA and Git ref.
> 2. GitHub searches the `.github/workflows` directory in your repository for workflow files that are present in the associated commit SHA or Git ref of the event.
> 3. A workflow run is triggered for any workflows that have on: values that match the triggering event. Some events also require the workflow file to be present on the default branch of the repository in order to run.

Comment: I see, thanks! Then, why is it even possible to say `on: push: [branch1, branch2]`?

Comment: The pre-requisite is that the action files are available in the respective branch. Then you would be able to test/build all other changes on respective branches.

Comment: @dockynodyerror assuming your workflows don't live in vain in a separate orphaned branch, but in a `main` branch, then without specifying branches, every forked branch of `main` (each PR etc.) would execute the workflow, which is clearly not good if you only want to exec workflows on push to `main`.