# Github Actions only triggers on default branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am trying to run a specific workflow when the PR is merged to `dev` branch or changes are committed to `dev` branch directly. Of course, `dev` branch is not a default one.
To realize that, I set filters like this.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
```

But this workflow is not triggered. Seems Github Actions only triggers on default branch.
I am not sure if this is a bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which branch should workflow files be located on for GitHub Actions to execute them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110223/which-branch-should-workflow-files-be-located-on-for-github-actions-to-execute-t)

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow won't be triggered unless the workflow file is also present on that branch. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110799/6310633 .